# React String Constants

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I want to abstract all strings in my application to a centralized file. I could do the following:

strings.js:

```js
export const MY_STRING = "foobar";
```

component.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { MY_STRING } from "strings";

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{MY_STRING}</div>
    }
}
```

But this seems like it could become slow at runtime for a large amount of interpolations. Is there a way to add these strings at build time via webpack to avoid interpolation?

Comment: Shouldn't the transpiler replace `{MY_STRING}` with the string itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Webpack Define](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) plugin:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  SOME_VARIABLE: "Hello World",
});
```

Honestly though, there is no harm to just having the `strings.js` file, and it will make your application infinitely easier to reason about. Also, once you start getting more complex strings or doing string templating, then that has to be done at runtime and so you'll end up with a `strings.js` anyways. It would not be fun to have your strings split between Webpack config and `strings.js`.